# mysql: unique constraint on big table

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, database-deadlocks

Hi I would like to hear some comments or experience on having a unique constraint on multiple columns(4 columns) on a big table and index on individual columns and the table gets updated very frequently, I am using mysql database and the unique constraint is required for frequent reads and individual column index is also used at other parts of the application read. will it have any side effect in future, it will maximum have of 1-2 million records.

The indexes are inevitable and kindly suggest me is it right to do and also I would like to know this table gets updated frequently, is there anything can be done at the  database level to prevent deadlocks.

Comment: can you create your own benchmark for this? It depends a bit on size of index, and how varied the values changes. Deadlock avoiding is getting the right indexes and doing transactions acquiring locks in the same order, and/or handling the deadlock.

Comment: Each index decreases modifying queries performance. If "the table gets updated very frequently" and this process is more critical than fast data retrieving then save unique index (think carefully about columns order in its expression!) but remove all individual ones.

Comment: Thank you @Akina your comment point is more helpful.

Comment: Thank you @danblack I am reading about deadlock and indexes.